# How can I rename multiple files in Eclipse?

Tags: regex, eclipse, user-interface, filenames, batch-rename

I'd like to rename multiple files(/resources) in Eclipse.

Functionality by order of usefulness:

1. Rename files in search results (i.e. search for pattern, see which files match
2. Rename files using a regexp which runs on all filenames (e.g. `s/stuff(.*)\.c/stuff\1.c.old/`)
3. Rename files in the selection in the package explorer (F2 doesn't do this...)

How can I do this? Is there a relevant add-on maybe?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use [Jalopy](http://www.triemax.com/products/jalopy/features.html), unfortunately its not free. Am not sure how usefull it can be in your case.